# Passing data from an Activity to a Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android Activity as below.

```
public class DummyActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dummy_layout);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int dots = intent.getExtras().getInt("dots");

    }
  }
```

This activity gets the value of dots from another activity without any problem. 
Now I want to pass dots to the layout dummy_layout which is given below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <com.test.DummyView
        android:id="@+id/dummyView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried creating a hidden field in 'dummy_layout' but could not get it working. Is there any straight forward way I can do this ?. I need to access the value of 'dots' in the init method of 'dummyView' which is the class handling 'dummy_layout' as seen in the layout xml.

Comment: I don't get you... the layout is inside the Activity, since you set it as ContentView... Then simply find the View and assign its properties. What's the question, then?

Comment: what is dots? a method in the DummyView class or an xml attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
((DummyView) findViewById(R.id.dummyView)).setDots(dots)
```

in your `onCreate`?